# tfspreview, continuous integration, and external folders getting overwritten

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-web-app-service

The problem stated simply:

- using tfspreview.com account linked to Azure website.
- using continuous deployment build provided by Azure team.
- All works perfectly, when I check in:

  - code is uploaded to tfs server
  - Remote Host is used to build code
  - A drop folder is created with the compiled code
  - code from drop folder is published to Azure website

Now this is all good, but it always overwrites any external folders (not part of project) that are on the server.  I went into the process template and changed 'Clean Workspace' setting to 'None', but that didn't help.

If I build locally and publish using web deploy, things don't get overwritten.  What am I missing here? obviously it's something with the build process or drop folders not being aware of the publish settings.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ali B, it seems like this could be a bug in our code.  Can you give me some additional description of the external folders and how they were created on the server?

Comment: Hi Chris, I created the folder in a couple of ways and both of them exhibited the same behavior:

- Created on desktop, made hidden, and transferred using FTP client
- Created directly on server using FTP client

in both cases the folder kept getting deleted (and not re-created) when we did the CD build.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Let me look at why the TFS publish code is defaulting to removing files and the VS code does not.

Comment: I have found the issue and have a bug filed.  It should make our next sprint deployment on October 29th.